# Set-Operations with Overlay when columns match

Tags: python, geopandas, overlay

Lets go with the example at the geopandas [Documentation](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/set_operations.html). Say we have:

```py
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

polys1 = gpd.GeoSeries([Polygon([(0,0), (2,0), (2,2), (0,2)]),Polygon([(2,2), (4,2), (4,4), (2,4)])])

polys2 = gpd.GeoSeries([Polygon([(1,1), (3,1), (3,3), (1,3)]),Polygon([(3,3), (5,3), (5,5), (3,5)])])

df1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame([[1, 'A'], [2, 'B']], columns=['df1', 'name'], geometry = polys1)
df2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame([[1, 'C'], [2, 'B']], columns=['df2', 'name'], geometry = polys2)

ax = df1.plot(color='red', alpha=0.5);
df1.loc[[1],'geometry'].plot(ax=ax, facecolor='none', edgecolor='black');
df2.plot(ax=ax, color='green', alpha=0.5);
df2.loc[[1],'geometry'].plot(ax=ax, facecolor='none', edgecolor='blue');
ax.annotate('B', xy=(3.4,3.4), size=15, c='yellow');
```

[image]

How would I execute `res_symdiff = df1.overlay(df2, how='symmetric_difference')` to only perform the operation on the matching `name` (B) rows? [i.e.: where the yellow B is; only that block would be gone].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to select the rows of the GeoDataFrames before overlay:

```
df1 = df1[df1['name'] == 'B']
df2 = df2[df2['name'] == 'B']
result = df1.overlay(df2,how='symmetric_difference')
ax = result.plot(color='red', alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @gene. How would I replace `result` back into the original `df1` at the index of the (originally) selected rows?

Comment: Sorry, but it is another question